# Get keyboard status in WPF Application in Main-Method during startup

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

When my application starts up in the static void Main method I want to determine if a key like Alt or Ctrl is pressed and then start the Application in some kind of Option-Mode. How can I find out if a key is pressed during startup?

I found some samples already but they all import a windows dll, something I don't want to do.

Answer (score 9):

Use  Keyboard.IsKeyDown() static method will help you to check the state of the keys you're interested in.

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)
       || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt) )
{
    //Load in a special mode
}
else
{
    //Load standard mode
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to do it in the main method you will have to use

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte [] lpKeyState);
```

[docs here](http://GetKeyboardState)

because the Keyboard static members that you'd normally use do not work at that point:

[Keyboard.Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx)
[Keyboard.IsKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx)

But you could try to hookup to the [Application.Startup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) event and do your keyboard testing there.

Comment: he doesn't wanna do DLL Imports. Probably looking a way that is inside the .net namespaces itself.

Comment: You don't need to import anything when using Keyboard.Modifiers. But there is a slight chance that Keyboard.IsKeyDown and Keyboard.Modifiers do not work at the begging of the main method. Thats where he wants to use it. That's why I introduced him to GetKeyboardState. this will work in any case. There is nothing wrong or bad in using Dllimport unless you are in sliverlight of course.

Comment: Indeed it seems IsKeyDown in not working inside main. Will try something else.

Comment: As I said, there is nothing wrong with dllimport but you could try to hookup to the Application.Startup event and do your keyboard test there. I add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802703/keyboard-modifiers-during-application-startup) [SO]

I had the same problem and ended up checking for the keyboard modifiers in the `Loaded` event...

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind. I want to check the keys before any window is loaded because if the Ctrl-Key is pressed during startup I want to load a completely different window.
GetKeyboardState is the only thing that seems to work inside the main-method.