# detecting if shift was held when application started

Tags: wpf, arguments, startup

Is there anyway that I can find out if user has been holding Shift (CTRL or any other key) when she/he double click on application icon from desktop to start the application?

I have a WPF application where I want to be able to detect if the user has been holding any special  key when he/she started the application (by double clicking) so I can change some settings if the key was pressed.

I tried :

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
}
```

but couldn't find any way to detect the key down .

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this reliably. In case of a cold startup, by the time your code gets the chance to run the user might already have released the shift button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code in your application start-up event:

```
// Instead of the MessageBox you could write your code here
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Shift Pressed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this question: [Keyboard modifiers during application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802703/keyboard-modifiers-during-application-startup) This is probably what you're looking for.

Hope it helps.