# Difference Between RoutedEventHandler and EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

What is the difference between

```
this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
```

and

```
childWindow.MyEvent += new EventHandler(childWindow_MyEvent);
```

Comment: does `Loaded` is routed event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to know what's the difference between Events and Routed Events. These 2 articles might help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.100).aspx (a MSDN article)

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/ (a great article about Routed Commands that also contains a very nice explanation of Routed Events)

Answer (score 13):

In short, RoutedEvents are routed. They can bubble up or drill down the visual tree until they hit a handler.

Standard events are just plain direct subscription.

Comment: can we convert a standard event to RoutedEvents in UWP, I know that is possible in WPF. but not getting any reference for UWP.